# How to allow both landscape/portrait for tablets only

Tags: screen-orientation, android

I would like to enable screen orientation changes for my application in tablets only, while restricting the layout in phones to portrait only.  How do you do this?

Comment: Are you aiming to run your app on Tablets only? Or is it also for phones? Can you please throw some more light on your requirements, like if you app runs both on phones and tablets but you want to restrict the orientation changes only to tablet and not to phone, or something of the sort may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case, please read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html). It should give you an idea as to how to go about it. The `<supports-screens>` tag allows you to declare what sort of screens you want your app to support. However, if you read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen), it'll give you an idea about screen orientation.

Hope this helps.